# lodash convert Object of Objects to array of objects including key in it

Tags: javascript, lodash

sorry about poor explanation on the title.

basically i want to know if there's better way or shorter code to do my job. i recently started using lodash library.

so,

i have an object of objects like following.

```
   {
    key1:{ firstname: john, lastname: doe}, 
    key2:{ firstname: david, lastname: smith},
   }
```

eventually i wanna make them as following array of objects.

```
   [
    {ID: key1, firstname: john, lastname: doe },
    {ID: key2, firstname: david, lastname: smith}
   ]
```

and this is what i did.

```
const ArrayOfObjects = [];
    _.each(ObjectsOfObjects, (value, key) => {
        ArrayOfObjects.push({
            UID: key,
            ...value,
        });
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lodash's [`_.map()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#map) can iterate objects. The 2nd param passed to the iteratee function is the `key`:

```js
const input = {
  key1:{ firstname: 'john', lastname: 'doe'}, 
  key2:{ firstname: 'david', lastname: 'smith'},
}

const result = _.map(input, (v, UID) => ({ UID, ...v }))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You're awesome, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.entries` and `.map`:

```js
const input = {
  key1:{ firstname: 'john', lastname: 'doe'}, 
  key2:{ firstname: 'david', lastname: 'smith'},
}
const transformed = Object.entries(input).map(([key, obj]) => Object.assign(obj, { ID: key }));
console.log(transformed);
```